# Error Contraseña Outlook en PHPMailer

Tags: php, email, outlook

Estoy utilizando PHPMailer para enviar via SMTP un correo:

```
    <?php 
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
    
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';
    require 'Exception.php';
    require 'OAuth.php';
    
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
        );
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
    
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Host = 'smtp-mail.outlook.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
    
    $mail->Username = "correo@hotmail.com";
    $mail->Password = 'passwordOutlook';
    $mail->SetFrom("correo@hotmail.com");
    $mail->Subject = "Pagina web: " . $_POST['name'];
    $mail->Body = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: ". $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $mail->AddAddress("correo@hotmail.com");
    
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
      }
      
    ?>
```

Pero cuando le doy al SUBMIT para enviar, recopilo los LOGS y me sale lo siguiente:

```
> 2020-09-03 20:19:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2020-09-03
> 20:19:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2020-09-03 20:19:32 CLIENT ->
> SERVER: EHLO localhost 2020-09-03 20:19:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH
> LOGIN 2020-09-03 20:19:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden]
> 2020-09-03 20:19:32 CLIENT -> SERVER: [credentials hidden] 2020-09-03
> 20:19:38 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 535 5.7.3 Authentication
> unsuccessful [MR2P264CA0017.FRAP264.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM] SMTP Error:
> Could not authenticate. 2020-09-03 20:19:38 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

Comment: Password command failed. Estás seguro de que el usuario y la contraseña son correctos?

Comment: @Benito-B Totalmente, me acabo de logear con el correo y contraseña que ponia

Comment: Es muy posible que necesites crear una _application password_ en tu cuenta. Outlook, gmail y demás no hacen tan sencillo que te autentiques sin interfaz web, ya que todos usan OAuth2.0 y normalmente tratan de validar que sí eres tú... pero esta vez es un script desde una IP diferente a la usual.

Answer (score 0):

El problema podria ser el siguiente:

En primer lugar los datos de host para outlook son:

- **Nombre del servidor IMAP** Outlook.Office365.com
- **Puerto IMAP** 993
- **Método de cifrado IMAP** TLS
- **Nombre del servidor POP** Outlook.Office365.com
- **Puerto POP** 995
- **Método de cifrado** POP TLS
- **Nombre del servidor SMTP** SMTP.Office365.com
- **Puerto SMTP** 587
- **Método de cifrado SMTP** STARTTLS

mas información aqui: [https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/configuración-pop-imap-y-smtp-para-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/configuraci%C3%B3n-pop-imap-y-smtp-para-outlook-com-d088b986-291d-42b8-9564-9c414e2aa040)

Por lo tanto cambias en tu configuración del PHPMailer

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = 'SMTP.Office365.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Dado que te estas autentificando desde otra aplicación externa a outlook, este te bloquea, por lo tanto debes generar una *contraseña de aplicación*. Para esto sigue los pasos indicados en el siguiente link

https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/12409/microsoft-account-app-passwords-and-two-step-verification

Teniendo esta contraseña exclusiva para tu aplicación podrás hacer envío correcto de tus mails.

Comment: Te comento esta situación, ya que me ocurrió el mismo percance al hacer envíos con SwiftMailer. El mismo criterio de activar contraseña para aplicaciones se hace para gmail y yahoo (En algunos obliga a activar la verificación de 2 pasos en nuestras cuentas).

Comment: Muchas gracias por la rapidez de tu respuesta! Me ha ayudado mucho! Pero hay un problema, si lo hago desde mi servidor local (con servidor Apache de Xampp) me va perfectamente con tu configuracion, pero cuando subo los archivos al cPanel de la web, me salta de nuevo el mismo mensaje de SMTP ERROR: Password command failed, y no entiendo porque.

Comment: Debes generar otra contraseña para tu servidor, ya que técnicamente la dirección ip con la que intenta autentificar es distinta (por ende necesita otro permiso)

Comment: Eso mismo hice, y desde el servidor XAMPP en local no hay ningun problema, me lo envia al correo que le pongo, pero cuando subo los cambios PHP al host, sale lo de SMTP ERROR: Password command failed. No se si en el host hay que configurar al de SMTP. Utilizo SERED como hosteo.

Comment: Debe ser por lo que te indique anteriormente, genera una nueva contraseña, ponla en tu codigo, *pero no la ejecutes en local* (desde tu servidor Xampp), ya que Outlook la identificará como usada desde otro origen.

Comment: Lo hice como dijiste, dado que tenia bastante sentido, pero nada, me sigue saltando el mensaje de que la contraseña es incorrecta. Me puesto en contacto con el servicio al cliente del Host para comentar el problema porque he visto que ha mucha gente le pasa y la mayoria dicen porque puede que en el host haya alguna restriccion de conexion SMTP y que se configura en el cPanel de WHM, sabes algo de eso?